# Oracle schema export in windows with command prompt

Tags: oracle, export

I am trying to export a schema from a Oracle 12c database. I am doing this from a command prompt and need to have the files (dump and log) on my desktop.

The command I have written is as below

```
C:\Users\Suhas.S\Desktop>expdp username/password@TNS schemas=idbprod directory=dumpdir \ dumpfile=idbprod.dmp \ logfile
=expdp_idbprod.log version=11.2

Export: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Thu Aug 17 13:12:12 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
ORA-39087: directory name DUMPDIR is invalid
```

Can someone help me here please

Comment: `expdp` exports to the server, always. Old `exp` could dump on the client.

Comment: Mat, thanks for your response. I have Oracle 12c installed on the client(my PC). But the data i export will be used for import into 11.2g Oracle DB. for this only purpose, i am using the expdp command which has the version parameter. exp command doesn't has the version parameter and hence cannot import the exp dump file into a 11g database

Comment: so did you create a directory called dumpdir?

Comment: Yes....on my Desktop.....folder called dumpdir

Comment: what does this return: select * from dba_directories where upper(directory_name)='DUMPDIR'

Comment: SQL> select * from dba_directories where upper(directory_name)='DUMPDIR';
select * from dba_directories where upper(directory_name)='DUMPDIR'
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


I have connected via sqlplus via Command Prompt